# javax.swing.JOptionPane cancel button loop

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to write a while loop to allow my app to keep running until the user pushes `cancel` on the `JOptionsPane` . How do i do this?  I'm using `javax.swing.JOptionPane` `cancel` button loop.

This is the code so far the cancel button does not work.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyType2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    String strChoice, strTryStrig, strTryInt, strTryDouble;
    int choice, tryInt;
    double tryDouble;
    boolean done = false;

    while(!done)
    {
        try
        {
            strChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Whats My Type?" + "\n\n1) String\n2) Interger\n3) Double\n4) Quit the program\n ");
            choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);

                    switch(choice)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        if (choice == 1)
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct , Any input can be saved as a String.", "Result",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        if (choice == 2);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct ", "Result",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        break;

                        case 3:
                        if (choice == 3)
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct .", "Result",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        break;

                        case 4:
                        if (choice == 4)
                            done = true;
                        break;

                        default:
                        if(choice<=0 || choice>=5) throw new NumberFormatException();
                        break;
                    }
        }

    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number was not in the proper format.", "Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to simply add Click Listener to Cancel button to close your application?

Comment: How are you using JOptionPane? Are you using one of the supplied static methods? And if so which one?

Answer (score 0):

javax.swing GUI elements "run" until you close them. If you put in an infinite loop you want to cancel via button, i think you won't be able to do so as the gui is unresponsive unless you explicitely take care of threading.

If so, you can switch the loop condition to false via buttonclick..

Comment: yes correct direction but there are `JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION` and `JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION` implemented in API, it is very simple to test .....